# How do I use add_action on custom widget?

Tags: plugins, widgets, css

First hope you will take a look example widget http://pastebin.com/2cL7BmgF

There have male and female option. Let say I select male and I want add male.css to `wp_head`

When I put something like this into the code it's not working.

```
add_action('wp_head','load_face');
function load_face() {
  wp_enqueue_style('style', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/sample/'.$sex.'.css', null, null, 'screen');
}
```

Let me know what is the correct code to archive my goal. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when calling a function within a class you need to use $this

`prefixadd_action('wp_head',array(&$this,'load_face'));`

and you will need to populate the value of $sex

```
public function load_face($instance) {
  $sex = $instance['sex'];
  wp_enqueue_style('style', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/sample/'.$sex.'.css', null, null, 'screen');
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate for the explanation but I'm really blur.. grgrgr. I got this `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object` Question, actually.. where should I put the code into current plugin?

Comment: inside the widget class

Comment: I'm still in the dark.